# How to add duplicates lines to a file using Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I want to add duplicate lines I have tried but not able to get the desired output

I have used sed but end up with all lines duplicated (below code)

```
sed 'p' Data.txt > Output.txt
```

I have tried with awk but end up with all lines duplicated (below code)

```
while read line; do
 commacount=`echo $line|tr ',' '\n'|wc -l`
 atcount=`echo $line|tr '@' '\n'|wc -l`
 echo $commacount,$atcount
if [ "$commacount == '8' && $atcount == '3'" ]; then
{
awk '{print $0}1' Data.txt > tmp
}
else
{
awk '{print $0}' Data.txt > tmp
}
fi

 done < Data.txt
```

Data.txt

```
2009-09-12T05:18:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,CAM,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:24:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:24:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,RIV,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:25:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:25:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,WSN,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:27:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:27:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,HWL,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:29:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:29:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,BWD,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:31:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:31:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,ASH,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:33:00+10:00,,2303,Dump,ALM,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:00:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,ALM,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:01:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:01:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,ASH,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:04:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:04:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,BWD,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:06:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:06:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,HWL,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:08:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:08:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,WSN,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:10:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:10:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,RIV,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:17:00+10:00,,2300,Up,CAM,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:25:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,CAM,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:28:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:28:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,RIV,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:29:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:29:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,WSN,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:31:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:31:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,HWL,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:32:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:32:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,BWD,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:34:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:34:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,ASH,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:41:00+10:00,,2305,Dump,ALM,1,1,JUNM
,2306,Up,ALM,1,1,JUNM
,2306,Up,ASH,1,1,JUNM
,2306,Up,BWD,1,1,JUNM
,2306,Up,HWL,1,1,JUNM
,2306,Up,WSN,1,1,JUNM
,2306,Up,RIV,1,1,JUNM
,2306,Up,CAM,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T06:18:@00@+10:00,4505,Dump,CAR,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T06:21:00+10:00,2009-09-12T06:21:@00@+10:00,4505,Dump,SEA,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T06:24:00+10:00,2009-09-12T06:24:@00@+10:00,4505,Dump,KAN,1,1,JUNM
```

Output should be

```
2009-09-12T05:18:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,CAM,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:24:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:24:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,RIV,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:24:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:24:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,RIV,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:25:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:25:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,WSN,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:25:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:25:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,WSN,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:27:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:27:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,HWL,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:27:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:27:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,HWL,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:29:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:29:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,BWD,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:29:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:29:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,BWD,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:31:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:31:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,ASH,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:31:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:31:@00@+10:00,2303,Dump,ASH,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:33:00+10:00,,2303,Dump,ALM,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:00:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,ALM,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:01:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:01:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,ASH,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:01:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:01:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,ASH,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:04:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:04:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,BWD,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:04:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:04:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,BWD,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:06:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:06:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,HWL,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:06:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:06:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,HWL,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:08:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:08:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,WSN,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:08:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:08:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,WSN,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:10:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:10:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,RIV,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:10:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:10:@00@+10:00,2300,Up,RIV,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T05:17:00+10:00,,2300,Up,CAM,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:25:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,CAM,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:28:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:28:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,RIV,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:28:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:28:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,RIV,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:29:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:29:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,WSN,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:29:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:29:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,WSN,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:31:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:31:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,HWL,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:31:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:31:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,HWL,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:32:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:32:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,BWD,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:32:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:32:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,BWD,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:34:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:34:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,ASH,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:34:00+10:00,2009-09-12T09:34:@00@+10:00,2305,Dump,ASH,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T09:41:00+10:00,,2305,Dump,ALM,1,1,JUNM
,2306,Up,ALM,1,1,JUNM
,2306,Up,ASH,1,1,JUNM
,2306,Up,BWD,1,1,JUNM
,2306,Up,HWL,1,1,JUNM
,2306,Up,WSN,1,1,JUNM
,2306,Up,RIV,1,1,JUNM
,2306,Up,CAM,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T06:18:@00@+10:00,4505,Dump,CAR,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T06:21:00+10:00,2009-09-12T06:21:@00@+10:00,4505,Dump,SEA,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T06:21:00+10:00,2009-09-12T06:21:@00@+10:00,4505,Dump,SEA,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T06:24:00+10:00,2009-09-12T06:24:@00@+10:00,4505,Dump,KAN,1,1,JUNM
2009-09-12T06:24:00+10:00,2009-09-12T06:24:@00@+10:00,4505,Dump,KAN,1,1,JUNM
```

Is there anyway that I can get the above output.

I appreciate any help/suggestion.

Thanks
Sri

Comment: After you've accepted the appropriate answers, please explain your question clearly, instead of leaving a puzzle for us to solve.  Under what condition(s) do you want to duplicate a line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want duplicate lines which have 8 non-empty columns?

Try this:

```
awk -F',+' 'NF==8;1' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Kev this is what I want Thanks for simple solution.

Comment: @user790049 If this is the answer that you're going to use, you *really* should accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the sed version:

```
 sed '/^[0-9-]\{10\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:00+10/p' file.txt
```